# Widevine disappeared in Chrome in Yosemite

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I updated to Yosemite a couple of days ago. When I watched a streaming service using Google Widevine it all worked fine but after a reboot Chrome keeps asking for me to install Widevine, and when I do and restart the browser it is still not working. Widevine seems to be installed because it works fine in Safari.

Any ideas on how to solve this with Chrome? Never had this problem before.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The latest version of Chrome is 64 bit.  Widevine only runs on 32 bit browsers